# Domino Apps & LTPAToken

Tags: lotus-domino, lotus

I am trying to achieve SSO for applications deployed on Lotus Domino HTTP Server using an access management system (OAM). I have few questions around LTPAToken & Domino HTTP servers.

Env Details:
    a. Domino HTTP Server 7.0.2
    b. Applications deployed are based on Java.

1. Is LTPAToken mandatory for an application to work on Domino HTTP Server?
2. Can application create a session using headers variables etc, without the LTPAtoken.

Thanks,
Malli.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your two questions:

1. LTPA token is used by the session authentication method "Multiple Servers (SSO)". The Domino HTTP server supports basic authentication and session authentication too which both do not require the use of a LTPA token.
2. Yes - see answer to 1.

You can learn more in the [Securing section of the IBM Domino knowledge center](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSKTMJ_9.0.1/admin/conf_configuringsecurity_c.dita) - specifically in the following sections:

- http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSKTMJ_9.0.1/admin/conf_nameandpasswordauthenticationforinternetintranetcl_c.dita
- http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSKTMJ_9.0.1/admin/conf_multiserversessionbasedauthenticationsinglesignon_t.dita